# Why is there a fixed page width?

Tags: html, mobile

Here is the [full html of my test page](http://pastebin.com/BdVpFVnr)

It's essentially the below. When I browse to it on my android phone (v4.1) it has a large width and makes it extremely irritating to read because i have to scroll to the right and left. The font is also tiny. The resolution of the phone is 720x1280. I'm using the default browser. On firefox it reads fine (no scrolling).

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>lots of Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ahmad wth? why did you remove the android tag? ESPECIALLY when you didnt add a mobile tag.

Comment: Because this isn't an Android question.

Comment: @Doorknob: he failed to mark it mobile and it wasn't a question for general webbrowsers (works on firefox mobile)

Comment: I removed it because it's not Android related. But you're right, I should have added the mobile tag. Sorry for that.

Comment: well, the Android tag means it's about Android, meaning that you're writing Android code. You're not, so the tag is not relevant.

Comment: @Ahmad: good point your both right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a viewport `meta` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height;" />
```

Essentially, what this does is it will set the width and height of the page to the width and height of the device.